# Select a single check box

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code that only works when there are many check boxes. However when I only have one checkbox the code bugs. Basically what I want the macro to do is to select the ckeckbox as an object and align it to a cell it should also work if more than one checkbox. Could you please help?
Many thanks in advance. Please see code attached

```
Worksheets("Analysis Line Cupboards by Pick").CheckBoxes.Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, msoFalse
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 45
Range("A10000").Select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can align a checkbox (or any shape) on another shape, or on a cell with the left property.

Example, for an ActiveX checkbox in a Sheet to be aligned on cell B5:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Checkbox_1").Left = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Left
```

In your case (adapt it):

```
Sheets("Analysis Line Cupboards by Pick").Shapes("Checkbox name").Left = cell.left
```

Or, if you have multiple checkboxes, give them appropriate names and loop through them. For example, their names could be chbx_A, chbx_Hello, chbx_10 or something.

```
Sub AlignCHBX()
    dim shp as shape
    for each shp in Sheets("Analysis Line Cupboards by Pick").Shapes
        if shp.name like "chbx*" then shp.left = Sheets("Analysis Line Cupboards by Pick").Range("B1").Left
    next
End sub
```

This verifies that the shape's name starts with chbx to avoid moving other shapes. You can use this to differentiate certain groups of checkboxes, as well!

For a NON-ActiveX checkbox, use the following syntax to refer to it's left, for example:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("chbx_A").Left
```

For it's value:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("chbx_A").Object.Value
```

For `.Top` it works the same way. The `.Left` and `.Top` properties are numeric values measured in pixels. If you want to go to an absolute position, you can write `Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("chbx_A").Left = 150` for example. When you are making the shape's Left = to the cell's left, the code actually goes to see what Absolute value the left position of the cell is, and gives it to that shape. If I can elaborate, you could write:

```
 dim nbPosition as Double
 nbPosition = ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Left
 debug.print nbPosition 'It could say 40, for example, depending on column width
 ActiveSheets.Shapes("Shape1").Left = nbPosition + 10 'Will send it 10 pixels further than nbPosition
```

Comment: `activesheet.shapes("Button 3").left = activesheet.range("P10")` works for me but `activesheet.shapes("Button 3").top = activesheet.range("P10")` does not work. Instead the button moves to `.Top = 0` and aligns to the top of the sheet.

Comment: Oh. It should be `activesheet.shapes("Button 3").left = activesheet.range("P10").left`. Same for `.Top`. You have to specify the .Top for the cell too! Something `.Left` or Something `.Top` = a numeric value (measured in pixels). You can write `.left = 100` also, you'll see where it goes. Also, `activesheet.shapes("Button 3").top= activesheet.range("P10").top + 10` for example will send it near the middle of the cell.