# How to Copy and Select Charts, Pictures, etc. in VBA, Excel

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have code that copies a chart as a picture `AChart.CopyPicture` I want to paste it to `Destination as Worksheet`, but have it pasted as the same location as in original sheet where I copied my chart from. (so use `AChart.Left` and `AChart.Top`)

This would be very straight forward for me if I only had one chart in my source and destination sheet, but I have many charts.

So my proposed soultion is Select new Chart immediately after pasting it and set the `.Left` and `.Top` to correct values. I just don't know how to select the just pasted Piture?

My mind is not particularly set on this solution, I'm well aware that it could cause [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So feel free to approach my problem from a different angle.

Comment: wouldn't the pasted picture be the active element selected? if that's the case you can just manipulate the properties of that object straight away after pasting.

Comment: In other words you are saying that `Selection` Object will let me set those properties. Is that correct?

Comment: that is my thought at least without testing it or trying it. You can find the `.Left` and `.Top` properties of the chart you are copying and then apply them to the pictures, using the object model for each object to obtain and set these values.

Comment: The following question & solution might be able to help you align your many chart on the sheet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251847/select-a-single-check-box/

Comment: Scott Looks like you are correct. I wasn't able to repicatre your solution at first because I forgot to Activate "Destination" untill Dylan remminded me about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to modify the pasted chart with the `Selection` object. The `Destination` sheet needs to be the active sheet as well. If you want to copy every chart from the source sheet, you can use a `For Each` loop.

```
Destination.Activate
For Each cht In Source.ChartObjects
    cht.CopyPicture
    Destination.Paste
    Selection.Left = cht.Left
    Selection.Top = cht.Top
Next cht
```